# On React MaterialTable, example to code Edit Button when option.selection row is enabled?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React `MaterialTable` component, with option. Selection: true. When I select one or more rows, it is enabled on the Edit button on top/right.
How I code this button?  Witch action/option should I use?

Code:

```
      <MaterialTable
                  icons={tableIcons}
                  title="Table"
                  columns={this.getColumns()}
                  data={this.props.data}
                  options={{
                      filtering: true,
                      selection: true
                  }}

                  editable={{

                    onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                        console.log('OnRowUpdate');

                        setTimeout(() => {
                          {
                              this.props.setdata(newData);


                          }
                          resolve();
                        }, 1000);
                      }),
                  }}

            />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your solution is in material's page in [this link](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/)

and this is what page coded

```
<MaterialTable
  title="Editable Example"
  columns={state.columns}
  data={state.data}
  editable={{
    onRowAdd: newData =>
      new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve();
          const data = [...state.data];
          data.push(newData);
          setState({ ...state, data });
        }, 600);
      }),
    onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
      new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve();
          const data = [...state.data];
          data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
          setState({ ...state, data });
        }, 600);
      }),
    onRowDelete: oldData =>
      new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve();
          const data = [...state.data];
          data.splice(data.indexOf(oldData), 1);
          setState({ ...state, data });
        }, 600);
      }),
  }}
/>
```

i have some thing in my codepen maybe it will help you [my codepen](https://codepen.io/alibalouchi/pen/yLBVavB)

Comment: I already used this editable (onRowAdd, onRowUpdate and onRowDelete) and it works well clicking on the edit button located on the row ( when selection is not present).    When option.selection is present, the Edit button is on top and I still dont know how to dispatch some action (for example, a form)